# IsUserInRole Jetty constraints for business logic

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I need to check if a user is admin.

I'm using Basic-Auth and extensively making use of org.eclipse.jetty.websocket; I need to check constraints in my websocket handler.

I am using jetty.websocket not javax.websocket

```
//THIS THROWS AN EXCEPTION - AN HTTP UPGRADE REQUEST WON'T ALLOW FOR isUserInRole(String role);
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.*;
...
ServletUpgradeRequest upgradeRequest = (ServletUpgradeRequest) session.getUpgradeRequest();
upgradeRequest.isUserInRole("admin-role");

//DON'T KNOW HOW TO USE THIS
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.*;
...
security.getIdentityService().getSystemUserIdentity().isUserInRole(String string, Scope scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a better way please say. This is not pretty.

```
//in my MyWebsocketServer.java
...
if (ServerMain.hasRole(sess.getUpgradeRequest().getUserPrincipal().getName(),"admin-role")) {
...

//in my ServerMain.java
...
public static boolean hasRole(String usr, String role){
    Iterator iter = loginService.getUsers().get(usr).getSubject().getPrincipals().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        if (((Principal) iter.next()).getName().equals(role)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```